# Remove complete angular project built with Yeoman

Tags: yeoman

i used yeoman to scaffolding angular project structure, but now i have problem to remove all contents under the root folder, there's this "node_modules" folder, i can't delete it.
My OS is win7, does anybody know how to delete the project completely?

Comment: Do you get a permission error when you try to delete `node_modules` or something else?

Comment: No, actually i got what the problem is. when i try to delete, windows prompt a dialog saying: the folder contains items whoses name is too long for recycle bin. win7 can't handle this, you can use 7-zip's file manager to delete them.

Comment: Press `SHIFT` and `DELETE` to skip the recycle bin and permanently delete the folder.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same issue when I tried to remove a node based application on my own Windows 7 box.  I used this tool to remove the folder.

http://www.osmstudios.com/projects/path-too-long

Its written in Java so that is the only requirement.  Its free and open source.

https://github.com/DawsonG/PathTooLong

Comment: For those out here who don't want to install Java, I've written a similar tool which is available from GitHub: https://github.com/epsitec/Tools-RecursiveDelete

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily accomplished using the in-built Windows tool called robocopy which basically clones one directory into another. Create a new empty directory in the same location and use robocopy as shown below.

```
mkdir new_dir
robocopy /MIR new_dir long_name_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping to a drive letter.

```
subst x: C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5
```

Then go to x: and delete the files (they now have a smaller path)

Next delete the mapping

```
subst x: /D
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool is a java tool no install requiered and it works perfect

[PathToLongLinkSoftware](http://www.osmstudios.com/projects/path-too-long)

Answer (score -1):

When try to delete, windows prompt a dialog saying: the folder contains items whose name is too long for recycle bin. Win7 can't handle this, you can use 7-zip's file manager to delete them.

Answer (score -1):

if you have winrar installed in your pc then right click your app folder, click 'add to archive' option
then tick the 'delete files after archiving', then delete the archived file. :)