# removing node_modules folder

Tags: windows, npm, directory, yeoman

### The problem:

I've created a yeoman project by mistake on my windows box. Via explorer when I try to delete it I get an error saying that the path is too long.

[image: Source too long error]

### Several Solutions:

- https://superuser.com/q/78434/9546
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28999343/145682
- [Remove complete angular project built with Yeoman](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20463598/145682)

But is there a script based solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write powershell to this effect relying on `npm`

```
PS C:\code\yeoman-foo> ls node_modules | foreach {
>> echo $("Deleting module..." + $_.Name)
>> & npm rm $_.Name
>> }
>>
```

After the above command completes you can remove the folder by the traditional ways...

Go to the parent folder containing the project folder, select it, and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>

Answer (score 23):

You could use [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf):

```
npm install -g rimraf
rimraf C:\code\yeoman-foo
```

Comment: This is insanely helpful!!! I happened to work on someone else's code base recently & I faced the same issue as the OP. I have been reading various articles & trying different things to delete the node_modules folder on Windows but no avail. Added to my woes, there were nested dependencies. I installed the `rimraf` module as you suggested and ran it. Boy, was I pleasantly shocked to see that it deleted the whole node_modules folder in seconds!!! I am only less crying of joy!!! Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to use the force switch.  This script recursively removes any node_modules folder using PowerShell 3.

```
:> ls node_modules -Recurse -Directory | foreach { rm $_ -Recurse -Force }
```

Comment: This is an ideal solution, this will delete node_modules from sub-folders also. i'm just after running it on my dev directory.

Answer (score 2):

1. `npm install -g remove-node-modules`
2. cd to root and `remove-node-modules`
3. or `remove-node-modules path/to/folder`

Source:

https://github.com/j-quelly/node-cleanup

Comment: Thanks! This does take some time, but IS quicker than deleting from file explorer and doesn't move folder to recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I found so far (no installing or separate programs required) is to just run these commands in the root of your project (next to the node_modules folder):

```
mkdir temp_dir
robocopy temp_dir node_modules /s /mir
rmdir temp_dir
rmdir node_modules
```

For convinience you can also put this code in a .bat file and place it in the project root and run it whenever you want to remove the entire node_modules map

Answer (score -2):

Try this `rmdir node_modules /s /q`

`rmdir` is a native command in powershell. Used to Remove-Item.
`/s` flag indicates subfolders
`/q` flag indicates quite mode

Comment: What does /s and /q do ? consider explaining ur answer so that others including me can read understand

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed /s means to include folders and subfolders inside the folder. /q means quite mode.